# Vue.js - Laravel Populating datetime-local input field

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to populate my Vue.js Template to update a model

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="start_time" v-model="start_time">
```

Having issues pre filling the date-time field

```
start_time: "2020-02-12 22:00:00"
```

this is the data that i receive from api and i'm directly assigning it to my start_time variable

Just adding to the answer

use format

```
'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'
```

otherwise there will be an issue with AM and PM

Comment: How are you trying to pre fill the data??

Comment: I'm binding start_time to the input form

Comment: Ok. Have you set the `start_time` data property with the value? In fact, please can you just add all the code for your component.

Comment: ok will update the question now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MDN web docs for datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) the format should be `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm`. Therefore you'll need to update the value of your data property to be:

```
2020-02-12T22:00
```

Since you've using moment you can format the initial date with:

```
moment(dateString).format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm')
```

Replace `dateString` with the actual date string or property that contains the date string.

Comment: Yep .. got that .. how to convert it to this format

Comment: I mean the data i get from api is "2020-02-12 22:00:00" .. I'm trying to use moment now for conversion .. will update once i succeed

Comment: @AthulRaj I have updated my answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: Possibly should be HH instead of hh

Comment: That would all depend on whether the user wants a leading zero for 0-9 i.e. 02:30 instead of 2:30. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Note that for new work, momentjs has been deprecated.  https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 0):

Went down this rabbit hole and thought I'd share my process using Vue3 & Laravel 8+...

Using a Laravel model cast:

```php
class Delivery extends Model
{

  public $casts = [
    'delivery_date' => 'datetime'
  ];

  // ...
}

class DeliveriesController extends Controller
{
  // ...

  public function show(Delivery $delivery)
  {
    return response()->json(['delivery', $delivery]);
  }
}
```

Will give me a JSON datestring similar to:

```
console.log(props.delivery.delivery_date) // 2023-10-18T11:26:00.000000Z
```

So in my Vue component I can do something like

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="datetime-local"
      v-model="date"
      id="date"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
// ...

const props = useProps({ delivery: Object })
const date = props.delivery?.delivery_date.slice(0, 16)
</script>
```

And that seems to pre-populate the date for me...no library needed just get rid of the extra junk ;)